# How to extract a Dataset content n rows by n rows?

Tags: apache-spark

I have to output the results of a `Dataset` into a `Postgis` (spatial) database. `Spark` doesn't handle it and I had to write specific code that cannot be serialized. It means that I can't use `dataset.foreach(...)` method, and I have to execute my database insertions from outside `Spark` tasks.

But a whole
`List<Row> rows = ds.collectAsList()`
will produce an out of memory error.

And a
`List<Row> row = takeList();`
only returns the n first rows of the dataset.

Is there a way to read sequentially the dataset, so that I can read its whole content from the beginning to the end, extracting each time only a fixed amount of rows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try randomSplit method to split your dataframe into multiple dataframes.
For example, to split into 3:

```
ds.randomSplit(Array(1,1,1))
```